# Express E[AAB] in terms of marginal moments and E[AB] only

Tags: expected-value, covariance, joint-distribution, moments

For a pair of generic random variables $(A, B)$, I am trying to find a way to express

$$E[A^2B]$$

using *only* the marginal moments

$$E[A^k], E[B^k], k=1,2,\ldots $$ and the second joint moment

$$E[AB].$$

Neither $E[A^k B^j]$ nor $Cov[A^k, B^j]$ are known unless $k=j=1$. Any ideas?

Comment: It cannot be done unless you make a restrictive assumption about the joint distribution.